# RecyclerView и Button проблема

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview, button, ui

есть xml разметка . в RecyclerViewя загружаю данные с апи(список товаров)
проблема в том что после того как данные подгружаються то кнопка "Next>" пропадает куда то. не могу понть где ошибка и в чем проблема

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.25" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_conteiner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_page"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next >" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопка у вас не помещается на экран. Установите высоту для RecyclerView так, чтобы он занимал всё место между верхними и нижними кнопками. Например так, через вес:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_conteiner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```